# Ping without opening a window

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to use the `system("ping www.google.com")` without opening a tab/window on your Windows machine, while still getting a return value?

If not, are there any other ways to ping a website without an external window opening, while still getting a return value?

Comment: I have already been though it and can't seem to find an answer @AyxanHaqverdili

Comment: are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes as mentioned, it is on windows. @AyxanHaqverdili

Comment: For windows example of C++ ping [is here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/ping).

Comment: `CreateProcess` and read from the `stdin` handle.

Comment: Use Win32 API instead of `std::system`. Google "win32 ping" and see what comes up.

Comment: I am also trying to get a return out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you're on Windows, then example of full source code in C++ for Ping [is here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/ping), using only WinAPI.